# PHP create css classes + some attribute`s

Tags: php, html, css

First the page: [MyPage](http://skeptar.bplaced.net/Startseite)
You can create a new account or take this: (if you want to test the page)

```
username = admin
password = 123
```

I create at the moment a page, on this page you can create "Links" (name + url). Now i want the option that the user can design the own links, as example the background-color, padding or font-size. I want to save all these information in my database here is a little picture:

[image]

This information are required to create an new link.

```
home_id = link id
home_user_id = user id
home_link_name = link name
home_link_url = link url
home_background_color = link background-color
```

Now my problem: 
Every single link need an own class (name + attribute`s). How can i create that with PHP?

Comment: what do you mean every single link needs its own class, why do you believe that?

Comment: Because every link get his own attribute`s with his own values

Comment: so you probably want to setup a table. user_id, class_name, value... Then pull the style from there.

Comment: Ok, but i think i should take the home_id(link_id) and not the user_id? Can i create then with this table a css file? How can i do this?

Comment: You want to echo the style with the bg-color in for each user, i would say you should store it in a session on login then you can echo the variabel in a css style.